# Incorrect sorting when rows in lock mode (UPDATE)

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am using:

- Node.js - v16.13.0
- Postgresql - postgres (PostgreSQL) 14.0 (Debian 14.0-1.pgdg110+1)
- Sequelize - ^5.12.3
- Isolation level for SQL transactions - READ COMMITTED

**Problem Description**

I have a `Wallets` table in my database - [table screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pdSrm.png)

I am doing two parallel transactions.

In the first transaction, I am getting all wallets with order DESC and with lock mode `UPDATE` and update the balance of the biggest wallet to 1.

In the second transaction, I am getting all wallets with order DESC and lock mode `UPDATE`. The second transaction waits until the first one completes and it is correct, but order works incorrect.

The wallet that was the largest remains in the first place in the list sorted in descending order, although its value has been changed to 1. This wallet should have gone to last place.

I think the problem is that the database does not re-sort the result after executing the first transaction.

```
Executing (d5f9d12f-7646-4129-9f4b-f133d89a6874): START TRANSACTION;
Executing (7090320d-4acf-41bc-a8b5-c0377c1324a0): START TRANSACTION;
Executing (d5f9d12f-7646-4129-9f4b-f133d89a6874): SELECT "id", "address", "balance", "createdAt", "updatedAt" FROM "Wallets" AS "Wallets" ORDER BY CAST("balance" AS NUMERIC) DESC FOR UPDATE;
Executing (7090320d-4acf-41bc-a8b5-c0377c1324a0): SELECT "id", "address", "balance", "createdAt", "updatedAt" FROM "Wallets" AS "Wallets" ORDER BY CAST("balance" AS NUMERIC) DESC FOR UPDATE;
Executing (d5f9d12f-7646-4129-9f4b-f133d89a6874): UPDATE "Wallets" SET "balance"=$1,"updatedAt"=$2 WHERE "id" = $3
Executing (d5f9d12f-7646-4129-9f4b-f133d89a6874): COMMIT;
Executing (7090320d-4acf-41bc-a8b5-c0377c1324a0): COMMIT;
```

[Result of the last **SELECT** with order](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KBvK0.png)

But when I do second **SELECT** with sub-query, everything works correctly.

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
    (SELECT * FROM "Wallets" FOR UPDATE) w1
ORDER BY 
    CAST("balance" AS NUMERIC) DESC;
```

So I don't understand why query results don't re-sort after first transaction changes data. Who knows something about this, please, explain how best to work with this.

Comment: Once the query result is started to be streamed to the client it's not re-sorted by changes in the underlying data.

Comment: @TheImpaler Thank you for response! How can I better build queries with transactions to avoid such sorting problems?

Comment: If you need the information to be resorted after an update, you can either cache it in the UI and resort it there, or you can re-run the query again to produce a proper refresh after the update is done. I would tend to be inclined for the latter.

Comment: You could also set the column `balance` to the proper data type (numeric).  (To avoid having a sub-query).

Comment: A few things to understand. There is no order of stored data, the DBMS is free to store rows any way it chooses. If you do not specify `order by` is the query the DBMS is free to return results in any order it chooses, even different form how it is stored or different from the previous result ordering of the same query. The **only way** to get a deterministic order is to specify `order by`. The effect of `order by` terminates  with the query. If you want the result set (display)  to change you must re-query (assuming DB implementation only)

Comment: @TheImpaler Can you explain why data don't resorted after changes ?